# How do I get a property name instead of a property value?

Tags: java, reflection, properties

I have this class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

}
```

I want to make an Excel file, and before I put the values into the Excel sheet I need name and age as columns in the sheet. All I need to know is how to get the property names (and NOT the values).

So for example if I have:

name= "Marc" 
age= 26

I want to get "name" and "age" first instead of "Marc" and 26. How do I do this?

Just to be clear, the name and number of properties can vary so I can't hardcode "name" and "age", I need some way to iterate and get it. I know how to iterate and put it into the sheet. All I need help with is how to get the property name.

The closest I've got is getDeclaredFields(), but then I can't get further, because I can't get anything from that Field type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. `getDeclaredFields()` returns a `Field[]`. Iterating over this array and accessing the `getName()` method on each `Field` should to the trick.

To use your example:

```
Person p = new Person();
Field[] fields = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    boolean accessible = field.isAccessible();
    try {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(field.getName() + " - " + field.get(p));
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        field.setAccessible(accessible);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should probably also need to set `field.setAccessible(true);`

Comment: @Lino Good point, I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 2):

You can get field name. Here is an example:

```
Field[] allFields = Person.class.getDeclaredFields();
for(Field f:allFields) 
    System.out.println(f.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Person.class.getDeclaredFields()

it retun Field[] and you can get information for each Field.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine. Later you can iterate using the indices of field array to store/write the data.

```
Field[] fields = YourClassName.class.getFields();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to use the class as it is, and to avoid using reflexion, I suggest you use a HashMap, so you can add key-value elements. This way you will have 'legal' access to both the name and the value. For example, you can map.put("name", "George"); and then use them as you please. You can check the details here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html